# Objective C - Swift Bridging issue Xcode 6.3 -Screenshot provided-

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6.3

So, I found myself craving a framework to replicate iOS 6 folders animation. Luckily I found one called [JWFolders](https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders), which is pretty neat and useful, but my problem is the following:

I am doing my program in Swift, in Xcode 6.3, I imported the header file to the bridging thingy in the swift compiler settings, and as long as I don't try to use anything from that framework, it doesn't complain, but as soon as I try to use it and compile I get the errors shown in the image below.

(even with a simple declaration like this)

```
var folder = JWFolders()
```

[image]

Comment: You can actually copy the text from the green area. This is often more convenient than taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

So, If anyone was wondering, I got it working. I contacted the developer and asked for help, and he nicely told me I was forgetting to add the source code files ".m" to the source compiling files.

After that it worked.